# Saving a file in resource folder of project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Like following,

[image]

The Media.html file is located in the folder of project.

How can I save this file outer user's local disk?

EDITED

**Sorry for question insufficiently. I mean how copy a resource file like Media.html to  disk programatically, in runtime, not VS2010 environment.

Comment: Right-click that folder and select "Open folder in Window Explorer"?

Comment: Right click on the file, then click open containing folder then find the file and copy it everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You may use C#'s file handling techniques, use `File.Copy` method. Please go [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-copy)